# Как отфильтровать список из data classа

Tags: android, kotlin, filter, mvp

Имеется JSON response:

```
{
    "response" : [
        {
            "f_name"    : "иВан",
            "l_name"    : "ИваноВ",
            "birthday"  : "1987-03-23",
            "avatr_url" : "https://2.cdn.echo.msk.ru/files/avatar2/2561900.jpg",
            "specialty" : [{
                "specialty_id" : 101,
                "name"  : "Менеджер"
            }]
        },
        {
            "f_name"    : "Петр",
            "l_name"    : "петроВ",
            "birthday"  : null,
            "avatr_url" : "https://2.cdn.echo.msk.ru/files/avatar2/1253126.jpg",
            "specialty" : [{
                "specialty_id" : 101,
                "name"  : "Менеджер"
            }]
        },
        {"f_name"   : "ЕКАТЕРИНА",
        "l_name"    : "пертрова",
        "birthday"  : "1990-01-07",
        "avatr_url" : "",
        "specialty" : [{
            "specialty_id" : 102,
            "name"  : "Разработчик"
            }]
```

и соответствующий data class в модели:

```
data class Response(
    @SerializedName("avatr_url")
    val avatrUrl: String,
    val birthday: String,
    @SerializedName("f_name")
    val fName: String,
    @SerializedName("l_name")
    val lName: String,
    val specialty: List<Specialty>
)
data class Specialty(
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName("specialty_id")
    val specialtyId: Int
)
```

Требуется отфильтровать список элементов Response для вывода в RecyclerView для каждой профессии.
В Presentere загружаю данные для всего списка:

```
val data = Employee.repository.getEmployeesInfo() 
                    .response
```

Каким образом нужно отфильтровать список элементов по свойству specialtyId для формирования списка людей только одной професии?

Answer (score 0):

```
 val result = mutableListOf<Response>()
    for (i in data) {
        for (j in i.specialty)
            if (j.specialtyId == 2) result.add(i)
    }
    return result
```

Comment: Уверены, что специальность всегда одна, и break при этом не нужен?

Comment: @YuraIvanov так наоборот же! я в этом как раз НЕуверен, поэтому и break нет. ID в любом случае уникальный и одна специальность не будет дублироваться у одного человека. а вот то, что человек может иметь много специальностей - допускаю

Comment: Даже если данные такие, что специальность с определенным кодом может быть только одна (что логично), то дополнительные итерации по остальным специальностям просто не нужны, юзер уже добавлен.

Comment: @YuraIvanov понял к чему вы. согласен!